# Switching between pages in React-native also return information

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I can't send value to another page. locID, tourInfo, userName, userEmail I want to send this value. But I'm new to react-native, I don't know.

I want to post information in a different Componen.

Mapview.js (locID, tourInfo,) => ShowInfo.js

You can help me if you study the code. Actually, I have to do something very simple, but I don't know what to do.

I need to send the variables (locID and tourInfo) to the ShowInfo.js Page. To open my location on the map.

**Mapview.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {getDistance, getPreciseDistance} from 'geolib'; // Mesafe Fark hesaplama kütüphanesi
import MapView, {Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Callout} from 'react-native-maps'; // Harita kullanım Kütüphansi
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation'; // Anroide konum zaman aşımına uğramasını engellemek için kullanılır
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux'; // yan menü açma ve sayfalar arasında geçiş de kullanılır (cihazın geri tuşu triği var)
import {
  StyleSheet, // Stil Sayfası
  Image,
  View,
  Dimensions, // Ekran Pencere Boyurları anlık çeker App dizaynı ona göre yapar
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'; // Düz doğrular yada levhalar yapmak için kullanılır
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions'; // İki mesafe arasında rota oluşturan kod
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker'; // Kamera kulanma ve cihazdan app resim video yükleme kütüphanesi

import * as firebase from 'firebase'; // firebase kütüphanesi importedildi

let locationRef = db.ref('/Location');

import {db} from '../../components/dbConfig/config';
import {requestAuthorization} from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(db);
}
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

export default class Mapview extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
      error: null,
      coords: [],
      places: null,
      selectedLat: '',
      selectedLang: '',
      distance: '',
    };
  }
  getLocation = () => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      this.setState({latitude: position.coords.latitude});
      this.setState({longitude: position.coords.longitude});
    });
  };
  setLatLang = (lat, lng) => {
    this.setState({selectedLat: lat});
    this.setState({selectedLang: lng});
  };

  showCoords() {
    const arrayMarkers = [];
    var coordsLatLang = [];
    var allCoords = [];
    var selectedCoordLat = [];
    var selectedCoordLang = [];
    var dis = [];

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      var userLat = position.coords.latitude;
      var userLang = position.coords.longitude;

      for (let index = 0; index < this.props.locCoord.length; index++) {
        coordsLatLang = this.props.locCoord[index].split(',');
        allCoords.push(this.props.locCoord[index].split(','));
        selectedCoordLat.push(allCoords[index][0]);
        selectedCoordLang.push(allCoords[index][1]);
        dis.push(
          getDistance(
            // Mesafe Hesaplama fonciyonu 2 boyutlu
            {latitude: userLat, longitude: userLang},
            {
              latitude: selectedCoordLat[index],
              longitude: selectedCoordLang[index],
            },
          ),
        );

        var lat = coordsLatLang[0];
        var lng = coordsLatLang[1];

        arrayMarkers.push(
          <Marker
            pinColor={'#24012f'}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: Number(lat),
              longitude: Number(lng),
            }}>
            <Callout
              tooltip
              style={{position: 'relative'}}
              onPress={() => {
                this.setLatLang(
                  selectedCoordLat[index],
                  selectedCoordLang[index],
                );
   

                **if ((dis[index] / 1000).toFixed(2) < 0.5) { ----------------------------
                  Actions.ShowInfo({
                    locationID: this.props.locationID,
                    userName: this.props.userName,
                    rating: this.props.rating,
                    locID: this.props.locID,
                  });
                }**----------------------------------------------------------
              }}>
              <LinearGradient
                start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
                end={{x: 1, y: 0}}
                style={{borderRadius: 20}}
                colors={['#531c5c', '#4b5cab']}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    alignContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    flex: 1,
                    padding: 15,
                  }}>
                  <Text
                    style={{color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20}}>
                    {this.props.locNames[index]}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{marginTop: 5, color: 'white'}}>
                    Puanı:{this.props.TourLocRating[index].toFixed(2)}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>
                    Mesafe:{(dis[index] / 1000).toFixed(2)}KM
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{marginTop: 5, color: 'white', marginBottom: 5}}>
                    Rota Oluşturmak İçin Tıklayın!
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </LinearGradient>
            </Callout>
          </Marker>,
        );
      }
    });

    this.setState({places: arrayMarkers});
  }

  openCam() {
    // kamera Başalama kodu
    ImagePicker.launchCamera(response => {
      // Kamerayı başlatır
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = {uri: response.uri};

        // You can also display the image using data:  // Verileri kullanarak da görüntüyü görüntüleyebilirsiniz:
        // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

        this.setState({
          avatarSource: source,
        });
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.showCoords();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getLocation();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.images);
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            alignItems: 'center',
            width: width,
            height: height * 0.08,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.goBack();
            }}>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: width * 0.05,
                height: height * 0.03,
                marginTop: 15,
                marginBottom: 10,
                marginLeft: 5,
              }}
              source={require('../../img/back.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Image
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={{marginLeft: width * 0.17}}
            source={require('../../img/headerText.png')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.lineFooterStyle]} />
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          region={{
            latitude: this.state.latitude,
            longitude: this.state.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          style={{flex: 1}}>
          {this.state.places}

          <MapViewDirections // Rota Oluşturmak
            precision={'high'}
            origin={{
              latitude: this.state.latitude,
              longitude: this.state.longitude,
            }} // Mevcut Konum
            destination={{
              latitude: this.state.selectedLat,
              longitude: this.state.selectedLang,
            }} // Hedef Konum
            apikey={'AIzaSyAYGO8DoGtW-v8lEdDbtagGNp5ogtAA8ok'}
            strokeWidth={6}
            strokeColor="#531959"
          />
        </MapView>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              width: width * 0.2,
              height: width * 0.2,
              marginTop: -height * 0.17,
              marginLeft: width * 0.4,
            }}
            onPress={() => this.openCam()}>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: width * 0.2,
                height: width * 0.2,
                marginTop: 15,
                borderRadius: 25,
              }}
              source={require('../../img/ARLogo.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.lineFooterStyle} />
        <View style={styles.footerStyle}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.styleInBottombar}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Mainpage')}>
            <Image
              style={styles.navItemHomeStyle}
              source={require('../../img/Home.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.styleInBottombar}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Discover')}>
            <Image
              style={styles.navItemBookmarkStyle}
              source={require('../../img/Bookmark_2.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.styleInBottombar}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MyProfile')}>
            <Image
              style={styles.navItemProfileStyle}
              source={require('../../img/Profile.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**ShowInfo.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

import {AirbnbRating, Rating} from 'react-native-ratings'; // puanlama kütüphanesi Yıldız verme
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'; // düz lehva cigi oluşurmak
import * as firebase from 'firebase'; // firebase kütüphanesi importedildi
import {SliderBox} from 'react-native-image-slider-box'; // resim gösterme slider yapama kütüphanesi
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window'); // Ekran
import Comment from '../HorizontalSlider/Comment'; // yatay kaydıma yapabilmek için kullanılır.
let userRef = db.ref('/Users');
let commentsRef = db.ref('/LocationComments');
let locationRef = db.ref('/Location');
import {db} from '../../components/dbConfig/config';
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(db);
}

const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
const loccommentRef = rootRef.child('LocationComments');

let addItem = (comment, locationID, userName, rating, comments, locID) => {
  // kullanıcı konuma yorum yapma işlemi
  loccommentRef.push({
    comment: comment,
    LocationID: locationID,
    username: userName,
    users: [],
    rating: rating,
  });
  var count = 0;
  var newRating = 0;
  for (let index = 0; index < comments.length; index++) {
    if (locID == comments[index].LocationID) {
      count++;
      newRating += comments[index].rating;
    }
  }
  var generalNewRating = (newRating + rating - 1) / count;
  locationRef.child(locID).update({Rating: generalNewRating});
};

export default class ShowInfo extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      locInfo: [],
      comments: [],
      comment: '',
      userName: '',
      userEmail: '',
      rating: '',
      users: [],
    };
  }

  ratingCompleted = rating => {
    this.setState({rating: rating});
  };

  getUserData() {
    userRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      let users = Object.values(data);
      this.setState({users: users});
    });
  }

  getComments() {
    commentsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      let comments = Object.values(data);
      this.setState({comments: comments});
    });
  }

  getLocationData() {
    locationRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      let locInfo = Object.values(data);
      this.setState({locInfo: locInfo});
    });
  }

  getUserName = () => {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.state.users.length; index++) {
      if (this.props.userEmail == this.state.users[index].email) {
        return this.state.users[index].username;
      }
    }
  };
  updateRating = () => {
    var count = 0;
    for (let index = 0; index < this.state.comments.length; index++) {
      if (this.props.locID == this.state.comments[index].LocationID) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    locationRef.child(this.props.locID).update({
      Rating:
        (this.state.locInfo[this.props.locID].Rating + this.state.rating) /
        count,
    });
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getLocationData();
    this.getUserData();
    this.getComments();
  }
  inRender(images, commentContext, comments, locCoord, locNames) {
    console.log(this.state.locInfo[2].Rating, '------');
    if (this.getUserName() != null) {
      this.setState({userName: this.getUserName()});
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < this.state.locInfo.length; index++) {
      if (this.props.locID == this.state.locInfo[index].ID) {
        images = this.state.locInfo[index].Image.split(',');
        console.log(
          '  :LocID değeri********* ',
          this.state.locInfo[index],
          '  --00ss-  ',
          index,
        );

        locCoord.push(this.state.locInfo[index].Coordinate);
        console.log(locCoord);
        locNames.push(this.state.locInfo[index].Name);
      }
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < this.state.comments.length; index++) {
      if (this.props.locID == this.state.comments[index].LocationID) {
        comments.push(this.state.comments[index]);
      }
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < comments.length; index++) {
      if (comments[index].username != '') {
        commentContext.push(
          <Comment
            username={comments[index].username}
            comment={comments[index].comment}
            rating={comments[index].rating}
          />,
        );
      }
    }
    return images;
  }
  render() {
    var locNames = [];
    var images = [];
    var comments = [];
    var commentContext = [];
    var locCoord = [];
    var retImages = this.inRender(
      images,
      commentContext,
      comments,
      locCoord,
      locNames,
    );
    var TourLocRating = [];
    TourLocRating.push(this.props.rating);
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            alignItems: 'center',
            width: width,
            height: height * 0.08,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.goBack();
            }}>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: width * 0.05,
                height: height * 0.03,
                marginTop: 15,
                marginBottom: 10,
                marginLeft: 5,
              }}
              source={require('../../img/back.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Image
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={{marginLeft: width * 0.17}}
            source={require('../../img/headerText.png')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.lineFooterStyle]} />
        <ScrollView>
          <SliderBox
            style={{height: height * 0.4, marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5}}
            imageLoadingColor="white"
            dotColor="white"
            inactiveDotColor="#90A4AE"
            autoplay
            disableOnPress
            circleLoop
            images={retImages}
            // Dizi olarak tutulur resimin ya yolu yada linki bulunur
            //currentImageEmitter={index => locName = imgSliderHolder[index].Name } //Resim üzerinde lokasyonun adını gösterebilirsin. Resim geldiğinde gerçekleşen func.
            //onCurrentImagePressed={index => Actions.ShowInfo({ locImage: images[index], tourName: imgSliderHolder[index].Name, info: imgSliderHolder[index].Info })}
          />
          <View style={{marginLeft: 15}}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                <View style={{marginTop: 30}}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: '#171c69',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      fontSize: 15,
                      marginLeft: height * 0.01,
                    }}>
                    {this.props.tourName}
                  </Text>
                  <LinearGradient
                    style={styles.gradientLineStyle}
                    start={{x: 0, y: 1}}
                    end={{x: 1, y: 1}}
                    colors={['#3E276F', '#F9F7F6']}
                  />
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.BtnStyleLogin}
                  onPress={() =>
                    Actions.LocMapview({
                      locCoord: locCoord,
                      locNames,
                      kind: 'location',
                      TourLocRating,
                    })
                  }>
                  <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Başla</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <Rating
                    readonly={true}
                    startingValue={this.props.rating}
                    style={{paddingVertical: 10}}
                    imageSize={20}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: width * 0.02,
                      marginBottom: height * 0.015,
                      marginTop: height * 0.012,
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                    }}>
                    Puanı:
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.playSound()}>
                <Image
                  style={{width: 40, height: 40, marginTop: height * 0.1}}
                  source={require('../../img/sound_button.png')}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                marginBottom: 15,
                marginTop: 15,
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
              }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.refs._scrollView.scrollTo();
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    color: '#171c69',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontSize: 15,
                    marginLeft: height * 0.025,
                  }}>
                  Hakkında
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.refs._scrollView.scrollTo({x: width, y: 0});
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    color: '#171c69',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontSize: 15,
                    marginRight: 15,
                  }}>
                  Değerlendir
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <LinearGradient
              style={styles.gradientLineStyle}
              start={{x: 0, y: 1}}
              end={{x: 1, y: 1}}
              colors={['#3E276F', '#F9F7F6']}
            />
          </View>

          <ScrollView ref="_scrollView" horizontal={true} pagingEnabled={true}>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                width: width,
              }}>
              <Text style={{padding: 15, textAlign: 'justify'}}>
                {this.props.info}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                width: width,
                padding: 15,
              }}>
              <TextInput
                style={{
                  height: 150,
                  borderColor: 'gray',
                  borderWidth: 0.5,
                  borderRadius: 25,
                }}
                multiline={true}
                onChangeText={comment => this.setState({comment})}
              />
              <View
                style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                <View style={{marginTop: 20}}>
                  <AirbnbRating
                    count={5}
                    showRating={false}
                    onFinishRating={this.ratingCompleted}
                    defaultRating={0}
                    size={30}
                    fractions={2}
                  />
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    width: width * 0.3,
                    height: height * 0.06,
                    marginTop: 15,
                    marginBottom: 15,
                    borderRadius: 15,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: '#1a345c',
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                  }}
                  onPress={() =>
                    addItem(
                      this.state.comment,
                      this.props.locID,
                      this.state.userName,
                      this.state.rating,
                      this.state.comments,
                      this.props.locID,
                    )
                  }>
                  <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Değerlendir</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: '#171c69',
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  fontSize: 25,
                  marginTop: 15,
                }}>
                Yorumlar
              </Text>
              {commentContext}
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.lineFooterStyle} />
        <View style={styles.footerStyle}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.styleInBottombar}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Mainpage')}>
            <Image
              style={styles.navItemHomeStyle}
              source={require('../../img/Home.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.styleInBottombar}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Discover')}>
            <Image
              style={styles.navItemBookmarkStyle}
              source={require('../../img/Bookmark_2.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.styleInBottombar}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MyProfile')}>
            <Image
              style={styles.navItemProfileStyle}
              source={require('../../img/Profile.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are displaying ShowInfo inside MapView, then you can pass that data as props like so:

```
<ShowInfo data={locID, tourInfo} />
```

Then in ShowInfo, get the data from props like so:

```
const locID = this.props.data.locID
const tourInfo = this.props.data.tourInfo
```

This might be your best bet as I see you're not using React Navigation, so I'm guessing one component will be rendered in the other.

Also, piece of advice, try to be consistent with how you use styling. Either keep all your styles inline or create a style object for all styles. It doesn't really make any difference performance-wise but it does make your code much easier to read.

Comment: Thank you very much brother. I am very happy. You are very nice people.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Example', { locID: "", tourInfo: "", userName: "", userEmail: "" });
```

in Mapview.js when you navigate to the other page, then in ShowInfo.js you get them like this:

```
var locID = this.props.navigation.getParam('locID', "");
var tourInfo= this.props.navigation.getParam('tourInfo', "");
var userName= this.props.navigation.getParam('userName', "");
var userEmail= this.props.navigation.getParam('userEmail', "");
```

Comment: Where would you like a description in ShowInfo.js? Constructor?

Comment: You can just use it outside the constructor inside the `ShowInfo.js` class

Comment: I have one more question? If you have time, of course?

Comment: Yes sure, go for it.

Comment: this.props.navigation.navigate ('Example', {locID: "", tourInfo: "", userName: "", userEmail: ""}); I need to get the values here from the Session. It keeps giving an error. I'm pretty new in React-native.

Comment: Where did you use it? And what is the error?

Comment: Here are the documentation for React Native on how to navigate from page to page, check it out: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/params/

Comment: I also used mapview.js. I wanted to access this way => /// Actions.ShowInfo ({
                     locationID: this.props.locationID,
                     userName: this.props.userName,
                     rating: this.props.rating,
                     locID: this.props.locID,
                   });
///
But its value has always been undefined.